# Python - NLTK train/test split

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk

I've been following SentDex's [video series](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nla4C-VYNEU) regarding NLTK and Python, and have constructed a script which determines review-sentiment using various models, e.g. logistic regression. My worry is that I think SentDex's approach includes the test-set while determining words to be used for training, which is obviously not preferable (train/test split occurs after feature-selection).

(Edited in response to Mohammed Kashif's comments)

Full code:

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from nltk.classify import ClassifierI
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

documents = [ (list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category) ]

all_words = []

for w in movie_reviews.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

def find_features(documents):
    words = set(documents)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

    return features

featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

np.random.shuffle(featuresets)

training_set = featuresets[:1800]
testing_set = featuresets[1800:]

MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
print("MNB_classifier accuracy:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(MNB_classifier, testing_set)) *100)
```

Already tried:

```
documents = [ (list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category) ]

np.random.shuffle(documents)

training_set = documents[:1800]
testing_set = documents[1800:]

all_words = []

for w in documents.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

def find_features(training_set):
    words = set(training_set)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

    return features

featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in training_set]

np.random.shuffle(featuresets)

training_set = featuresets
testing_set = testing_set

MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
print("MNB_classifier accuracy:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(MNB_classifier, testing_set)) *100)
```

Yields the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 34, in 
>      print("MNB_classifier accuracy:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(MNB_classifier, testing_set)) *100)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\util.py", line 87, in accuracy
>      results = classifier.classify_many([fs for (fs, l) in gold])
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\scikitlearn.py", line 85, in classify_many
>      X = self._vectorizer.transform(featuresets)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 291, in transform
>      return self._transform(X, fitting=False)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 166, in _transform
>      for f, v in six.iteritems(x):
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\six.py", line 439, in iteritems
>      return iter(getattr(d, _iteritems)(**kw))
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Updated post to include full code and trace for attempted solution. If you run nltk.download('all') then you should be able to run the code as is. Also included link to the video series this was taken from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so there are a couple of mistakes in the code. We will go through them one by one.

First, your `documents` list is a list of tuples and it has no `words()` method. In order to access all the words, change the for loop like this

```
all_words = []

for words_list, categ in documents:      #<-- each wordlist is a list of words
    for w in words_list:                 #<-- Then access each word in list
        all_words.append(w.lower())
```

Secondly, you need create feature set for both `training` and `test` set. You have only used feature set for `training_set`. Change the code to this

featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

```
np.random.shuffle(featuresets)

training_set = featuresets[:1800]
testing_set = featuresets[1800:]
```

So the final code becomes

```
documents = [ (list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category) ]

np.random.shuffle(documents)

training_set = documents[:1800]
testing_set = documents[1800:]

all_words = []

for words_list, categ in documents:
    for w in words_list:
        all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

def find_features(training_set):
    words = set(training_set)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

    return features

featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

np.random.shuffle(featuresets)

training_set = featuresets[:1800]
testing_set = featuresets[1800:]

MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
print("MNB_classifier accuracy:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(MNB_classifier, testing_set)) *100)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Does this approach solve my concern about the testing-set being included in the training data, or am I missing something?

Comment: Your welcome! Yes this approach solves your concern about the train test split as well. If this answer helped you can you please upvote and Mark it as the correct one :-)